# Are there any matrix operations that don't preserve determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to think of examples of operations that don't preserve the determinant of a matrix

Comment: Think sum of matrices...

Comment: In fact operations that preserve determinant would be more relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication by a scalar. Row swaps (that is left multiplication by one of the "elementary matrices). The list goes on.

Take a look at what RREF operations do to a determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A)\text{det(B)}$ every multiplication by a matrix with determinant $\neq1$ doesn't preserve determinant.